# Why oracle data base change listener is triggering multiple events in case of single update?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to track changes in one of the table in Oracle DB and write the data in elastic search. But for single update Oracle is trigerring multiple events.

Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class DBChangeNotification {

    /** The Constant LOG. */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBChangeNotification.class);

    private static final String SELECT_PARTY = "select * from PARTY";

    /** The data source. */
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /** The db change listener. */
    @Autowired
    private DBChangeListener dbChangeListener;

    /** The stmt. */
    private Statement stmt;

    /** The rs. */
    private ResultSet rs;

    /**
     * Inits the.
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     *             the SQL exception
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws SQLException {
        this.register();
    }

    /**
     * Register.
     *
     * @throws SQLException
     *             the SQL exception
     */
    private void register() throws SQLException {
        OracleConnection oracleConnection;
        Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
        if (connection.isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class)) {
            oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
        } else {
            throw new TalentApplicationException("Not an Oracle Connection", ErrorCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_NOTIFY_ROWIDS, "true");
        DatabaseChangeRegistration dcr = oracleConnection.registerDatabaseChangeNotification(prop);
        try {
            stmt = oracleConnection.createStatement();
            ((OracleStatement) stmt).setDatabaseChangeRegistration(dcr);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SELECT_PARTY);
            while (rs.next()) {
            }
            dcr.addListener(dbChangeListener);
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (TalentApplicationException e) {
            oracleConnection.unregisterDatabaseChangeNotification(dcr);
            LOG.error("Error in creating connection ", e);
        } finally {
            oracleConnection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And listener

```
@Component
public class DBChangeListener implements DatabaseChangeListener {

    /** The party repository. */
    @Autowired
    private PartyRepository partyRepository;

    /** The es pusher service. */
    @Autowired
    private ElasticSearchPusherService esPusherService;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeListener#onDatabaseChangeNotification(
     * oracle.jdbc.dcn.DatabaseChangeEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onDatabaseChangeNotification(DatabaseChangeEvent databaseChangeEvent) {
        TableChangeDescription[] tableChanges = databaseChangeEvent.getTableChangeDescription();
        for (TableChangeDescription tableChange : tableChanges) {
            RowChangeDescription[] rcds = tableChange.getRowChangeDescription();
            for (RowChangeDescription rcd : rcds) {
                Long partyId = partyRepository.getPartyId(rcd.getRowid().stringValue());
                System.out.println(partyId);

                // esPusherService.updateElasticSearchByPartyId(partyId);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when i update one record in Party table with below mentioned query i can see sometimes two party Ids on console sometime three and so on.

update party set t_id = 1788 where PARTY_ID = 1;
commit;

I am not sure like what is happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the multiple party ids that you see, are they the same party id (i.e. the one that you changed) or different ones?

Comment: yes they all are same.